# Issue with mounting SMB share on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, fstab, virtualization, nas

I know this has been asked before, but I think somehow I'm in a unique situation since none of the previous solutions I have found have worked for me. I'm trying to connect to a SMB share on a NAS on with the address of 192.168.2.2 with a share at `/volume1/Matt` but for the life of me I can't get it to work. I can connect to the share through the file manager by clicking on connect to server and entering `smb://192.168.2.2/` and then entering credentials.

- I have trying variations of changing the `fstab` including:

  ```
  //192.168.2.2/volume1/Matt /media/synology cifs credentials=/home/ubuntu/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
  ```
- The same but with `//192.168.2.2` or `//192.168.2.2/volume1` and all variations including and not including a ending slash.
- The same as above with the credentials typed in with `username=XXXX,pass=XXXX` mounting directly using `mount -t`

Something that might be of note is that this Ubuntu machine is on a vm and it's subnet is 192.168.1.0. I'm not sure why that would matter since I'm able to connect to the smb share through the file manager, but at this point I'm really not sure what the issue.

Comment: silly question, but did you by any chance forget to install `cifs utils`? (I've been there)

Comment: @JacobVlijm nope. It's installed. Thanks for the reply, though.